# Is it possible to use Firewire camera on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, camera, firewire

I work at school and we have old computer with windows xp, which is connected to microscope which has a digital camera.
Digital camera is connected to computer by firewire connection. camera is Olympus dp25.

But we recently purchased a new computer, and unfortunately the driver of the camera does not support
newer windows operating systems. So at this moment we can only install windows 10 with VMware, and then install windows xp
to get working camera.

but someone told us that maybe on Ubuntu can camera work, so I dont know which version of Ubuntu you recommend ?

It needs to have support for Firewire for Olympus dp25 camera.

And one other thing, I have read that through the program called Wine, i can install windows program. Is this true ?

that would be great, because then we could use the program from the camera.

I hope you can help me

Thank you

Comment: You may be able to do a test without installing Ubuntu by booting into an Ubuntu Live ISO. (See https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0). Years ago, I regularly used a Firewire video camera in Ubuntu, and it worked then. I suggest testing with the recent long-term-support version, 18.04. Use an application like "Cheese" to check the video input works. One caveat is that if this test doesn't work, it doesn't mean Ubuntu won't support your Firewire camera-- you may just have to install some other "packages" (e.g. software/drivers in Ubuntu) to enable it.

Comment: great, I will try that. Can I maybe install Ubuntu on VMware, and then try everything ?

Comment: I'm no expert on VMs, but it may not be a valid test, if your hardware is emulated. Would the Firewire adapter even be visible in the VM? I guess it doesn't hurt to try, once you've download the ISO.

Comment: ok. I wil try, and i hope it will work :)

Comment: See this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kino/+bug/6290

Comment: Ubuntu live is not great for testing extensions, it is designed mainly for you to taste the product.  Make your machine dual boot Ubuntu Windows or try an old Mac to fit your camera.